# Python 3, any better/cleaner way to write these functions that use for loops?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write code in the most simplest and cleanest way possible. I've found a few ways to shorten and simplify my code through functions that I've never seen before or through using other methods. I'd like to expand my knowledge on writing code using various (but simple) methods, and also expand my function 'vocabulary'.

Here are the functions:

**1. Perfect number**:
If a number's divisors' sum is equal to the number itself, it is a perfect number. We dont count the number itself as a divisor. E.g. 6's divisors are 1, 2, 3. The sum of the divisors is 6. Therefore 6 is a perfect number.

```
def perfect_number(num):
    if type(num) != int or num < 0:
        return None
    divisors = []
    total = 0
    for x in range(num):
        if num % (x+1) == 0:
            if num != x+1:
                divisors += [x+1]
    for x in divisors:
        total += x
    if total == num:
        return True
    return False
```

**2. Pattern**:
A function that takes a positive integer and prints a pattern as follows:

pattern(1): `'#-'`

pattern(2): `'#-#--'`

pattern(5): `'#-#--#---#----#-----'`

```
def pattern(num):
    if type(num) != int or num < 0:
        return None
    output = ''
    for x in range(num):
        output += '#'+('-'*(x+1))
    return output
```

**3. Reversed Numbers**:
A function that takes 2 integers. It goes through every number in the range between those 2 numbers, if one of those numbers is a palindrome (the same thing backwards  e.g. 151 is a 'palindrome'), it will increase a variable by 1. That variable is then returned.

`invert_number(num)` returns the opposite of num as an integer.

```
def reversed_numbers(low, high):
    output = 0
    for x in range(low,high+1):
        if invert_number(x) == x:
            output += 1
    return output
```

It is assumed that `low` is lower than `high`.

If I broke a rule or if this doesnt fit here, please tell me where I can post it/how I can improve. Thanks :)

Comment: Please repost this to the Code Review Stackexchange site.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: IF you decide to post this at Code Review, [read this guide first](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Comment: @Mast Will do. Thank you